# Flutter) I'm using riverpod, but my code doesn't find ConsumerStatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I chose riverpod as my state management library. I am reading the official documentation and writing the code. However, **the code can't find ConsumerStatefulWidget and ConsumerState, so it keeps showing a red line.** When I hover my mouse over it, a **suggestion pops up: "Would you like to create a class named 'ConsumerStatefulWidget?'"**

```dart
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends ConsumerState<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I tried pub get several times after flutter clean, but nothing changed.
It's a simple code that shouldn't be complicated, but I'm not sure why this problem occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out That I should use the flutter_riverpod package, not the riverpod package.